# Is route53 DNS exclusive to my domain?

Tags: amazon-route53

Are the NS addresses given by route 53 when I create hosted zone example.com exclusive to my domain example.com alone?

I am not an expert on server maintainance or DNS, so please help.

I am trying to develop a mapping service. My server is at example.com, that serves different content to a.com , b.com and c.com . I am currently using Domain Aliases on example.com, but this is not a feasible solution as I want to give out the NS address for example.com to the world to use and basically my server will than serve resource based on the requesting HOST.

In other words I am trying to run a DNS server, but will prefer to buy as a service from reputed company like amazon or google. Have they got something I need ? can route53 serve my purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

Those address are not unique to your domain. Domain A could have 1 set of 4. Doamin B could have a different set of 4. Domain C could have have the same set as A.

If you give a better example of what you want to do someone might be of more help.

Comment: Thanks @Mike , I am talking similar service as wordpress provides here https://en.support.wordpress.com/map-existing-domain/

Comment: You need to either run your own DNS servers or a service that'll create route53 zones and tell the client the NS servers to use based on the response from AWS. You could use a python library like boto to accomplish that

Comment: Thanks @Mike I would like someone to run the DNS server for me, I was  looking at the Google cloud DNS, and seems like they allow you to create your own DNS address with a hosted zone ... Do you think this might work for me?